# Synchronizing Plone 4 sites

Tags: plone, zope

I'm using Plone 4 for my sites and I was wondering if there is a way to synchronize two plone sites i.e. be able to synchronize my development site with my production site.

I have looked at [Zsyncer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ZSyncer) product and it appears it is no longer maintained. Besides, the last version is not compatible with Plone 4.

I am thinking of writing a custom script that will handle exporting of the data.fs files and the src files as explained in these two articles:

[Copying a remote site database](http://developer.plone.org/hosting/zope.html#copying-a-remote-site-database)

[Copying a Plone site](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/copying-a-plone-site)

Is there a better way of synchronizing two plone sites as described by my use case above?

Answer (score 0):

For keeping the code synchronized, you want collective.hostout

For the database, use collective.recipe.backup - you could probably also use hostout to import the backups

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solution will fit all your needs, but I use DemoStorage which is build-in to ZODB since version 3.9 (Plone 4 use it).

DemoStorage you have to setup on development instance and use Data.fs from production. All changes will be stored in memory or in separated file (it depends how you configure it), so changes in dev will not be visible on production. If you have both instances on the same server you can use Data.fs directly (without copying it), so it will be always synchronized.

To configure it you have to modify buildout. See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance#advanced-options

When on prod and on dev transactions changes the same objects (it happens occasionally) DemoStorage can show errors, Than you have to just reboot dev instance (if you use memory change storage) or remove file with changes and than reboot.